# position of detail disclosure icon

Tags: iphone

How would I figure out the location of the detail disclosure button/chevron?

I'd like to place some text above and below it aligned with the button.

Comment: Did you find out how to get the location?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a bad user interface and a reason to get your app rejected. Are you really sure?

Comment: Not really an answer to the question. Wouldn't this be better as a comment? (I'd like to know the answer for another reason)